# Best practice to substitute values on a page (tokens), without using (pure) PHP?

Tags: php, token, substitution

I am in currently upgrading a simple templating system for users who create their own pages, and would like them to be able to insert a set of their own *pre-set*  "variables".

Here is the workflow:

```
Client textarea -->  saved to database --> pulled from database --> page generated
```

Now here's an example of what their `textarea` might look like:

```
Hello my name is {{firstname}} {{lastname}}.  My phone number is {{phone}}.
```

Where of course the values of `firstname` `lastname` and `phone` all currently sit in a session variable.  And either when the page is **saved to the database** or **page generated** we need to replace `{{firstname}}` `{{lastname}}` and `{{phone}}` with items stored in the session.

What is being done now is:

```
$pat    = "/\{\{$match\}\}/";  //where $match is a preg_match for the rendered html to see if there's a "token"

if ($match === 'FirstName') {
            if (empty($firstname)) { $err[] = '{FirstName}'; } $str = preg_replace($pat, $firstname, $str);
        }
if ($match === 'LastName') {
        if (empty($lastname)) { $err[] = '{LastName}'; } $str = preg_replace($pat, $lastname, $str);
    }
```

The way that it's being done at the moment, is a convoluted bunch of code including `preg_match` and `preg_replace`  -- which I know isn't the "correct" or most efficient way to do this.  Is there any pre-set function in PHP to set your own token patterns, and observe them for a match?  Or perhaps a module that could be installed?  A class or observer?

I want to reiterate that I am not looking for a purely programmatic solution -- As this has already been done.  I am wondering if there's a pre-fabbed PHP solution built in that solves this specific quandary?  Or am I better off creating my own class and building this token machine from scratch?

I have found [this page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53716/how-to-substitute-values-on-a-page-without-php), but it only pertains to Drupal, and I am not using any out-of the-box CMS on this particular occasion.

Comment: how about any already existing php template engines?

Comment: I am only upgrading this small section of a much LARGER templating system ..

Comment: If you are going to vote me down, please give me an explanation so I can better edit my original post...